# Annotate and Extract to Group Attribute returns 'Sequence Item 0'

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I'm trying to build a query to count occurrences from distinct months in my SQL DB, using annotate and extract for this purpose.

Here is the code used:

**Model**

```py
class Results(model.Model):

   trip = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   created_on = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
```

**Query**

```py
from django.db.models.functions import Extract, ExtractYear
from django.db.models import Count

    res = Results.objects.annotate(month=ExtractMonth('created_on'))
    .values('month').annotate(count=Count('month'))

    OR

    res = Results.objects.annotate(month=Extract('created_on','month'))
    .values('month').annotate(count=Count('month'))
```

Both return:

**Error**

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\VIBRITO\Desktop\Projetos\webapp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 244, in __repr__
    data = list(self[:REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE + 1])
  File "C:\Users\VIBRITO\Desktop\Projetos\webapp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 268, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Users\VIBRITO\Desktop\Projetos\webapp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1186, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "C:\Users\VIBRITO\Desktop\Projetos\webapp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 106, in __iter__
    for row in compiler.results_iter(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size):
  File "C:\Users\VIBRITO\Desktop\Projetos\webapp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1017, in results_iter
    results = self.execute_sql(MULTI, chunked_fetch=chunked_fetch, chunk_size=chunk_size)
  File "C:\Users\VIBRITO\Desktop\Projetos\webapp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1052, in execute_sql
    sql, params = self.as_sql()
  File "C:\Users\VIBRITO\Desktop\Projetos\webapp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 449, in as_sql
    extra_select, order_by, group_by = self.pre_sql_setup()
  File "C:\Users\VIBRITO\Desktop\Projetos\webapp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 50, in pre_sql_setup
    self.setup_query()
  File "C:\Users\VIBRITO\Desktop\Projetos\webapp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 41, in setup_query
    self.select, self.klass_info, self.annotation_col_map = self.get_select()
  File "C:\Users\VIBRITO\Desktop\Projetos\webapp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 244, in get_select
    sql, params = self.compile(col, select_format=True)
  File "C:\Users\VIBRITO\Desktop\Projetos\webapp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 390, in compile
    sql, params = node.as_sql(self, self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\VIBRITO\Desktop\Projetos\webapp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\aggregates.py", line 76, in as_sql
    return super().as_sql(compiler, connection, **extra_context)
  File "C:\Users\VIBRITO\Desktop\Projetos\webapp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\expressions.py", line 618, in as_sql
    data['expressions'] = data['field'] = arg_joiner.join(sql_parts)
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, tuple found
```

Can anybody see what is wrong in my approach?
I've followed the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/database-functions/) for this query.

I'm using Django 2.1.5 and Python 3.7.0 on Windows.

Comment: What if you use `Count('pk')` instead?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem It returns an TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see the documentation of ExtractMonth it is postgreSQL only function, If you use a postgreSQL function with MySQL Database, of course its going to give error.

I would suggest using the raw query, or changing the database to postgres.

Comment: I did not find this information anywhere.
Do you know if TruncMonth has this same limitation?

Comment: To be honest, I have serious doubts that it will work, most of the functions we import from django.db.models.functions have "postgres only" limitation, 
I believe you will have to resort to writing custom query.

Comment: Solved it using extra in my query, just for reference: .extra({'week': 'week(monitors_results.created_on)', 'year': 'year(monitors_results.created_on)'}).values('week', 'year').annotate(count=Count('id')) will do the trick!